# Fixing the right button of a vanilla Javascript carousel

Tags: javascript

Against all reason, I'm trying to create a vanilla JavaScript carousel.
I am having two problems:
1. The images move left at widths of -680px as they should but when I tried to create the same function for the right button, the left value goes to 1370px making the picture off the screen.
2. I would like for it to slide left rather jump left (same for right), I managed to get it to do this but it doesn't work on the first slide, only from the second slide.
Here is the HTML code just for the carousel:

```
<div id = "container">
  <div id = "carousel">
   <div class = "slide"><img class = "slideImage" class = "active" src = "sithCover.png"></div>
   <div class = "slide"><img class = "slideImage" src = "darthVader.png"></div>
   <div class = "slide"><img class = "slideImage" src = "darthSidious.png"></div>
   <div class = "slide"><img class = "slideImage" src = "kyloRen.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id = "left" class = "button"></div>
<div id = "right" class = "button"></div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 100px;
   width: 680px;
   height: 360px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
}

#carousel {
   position: absolute;
   width: 2740px;
   height: 360px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: left 300ms linear;
}

.slide {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 360px;
   width: 680px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   transition: left 300ms linear;
}

.slideImage {
   position:relative;
   height: 360px;
   width: 680px;
   float: left;
}

.button {
   position: absolute;
   top: 340px;
   height: 60px;
   width: 60px;
   border-bottom: 12px solid red;
}

#left {
   left: 115px;
   border-left: 12px solid red;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#right {
   left: 693px;
   border-right: 12px solid red;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var carousel = document.querySelector('#carousel');
var firstVal = 0;

document.querySelector('#left').addEventListener("click", moveLeft);

function moveLeft (){
  firstVal +=685;
  carousel.style.left = "-"+firstVal+"px";
};

document.querySelector('#right').addEventListener("click", moveRight);

function moveRight() {
  firstVal +=685;
  carousel.style.left = "+"+firstVal+"px";
};
```

Here is a JSFiddle so that you can see what I mean: 
"https://jsfiddle.net/way81/8to1kkyj/"

I appreciate your time in reading my question and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: moveLeft +=685, moveRight +=685? shouldn't one of them be -=685? or perhaps -=1370 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it goes from `-685px` on left click and then to `+1370px`the next right click; You are always adding 685 to your `firstVal` variable.

```
firstVal = 0
//firstVal is worth 0

moveLeft()
//firstVal is now worth 685

moveRight()
//firstVal is now worth 1370.
```

The problem is that when you apply the `firstVal` to your CSS thing in the javascript, you create a string to get your negative value (where you apply the "-" sign infront of `firstVal`)

Instead, write them like this

```
function moveLeft (){
  firstVal -=685; //note we now subtract, the "-" should appear when the number becomes negative
  carousel.style.left = firstVal + "px";
};

function moveRight() {
  firstVal +=685;
  carousel.style.left = firstVal + "px";
};
```

Comment: NachoDawg, thank you.  I wasn't taking into account that the "-" was a string and was thinking firstVal was now -685 so to get it back to 0 I would have to add 685.  It solved my problem!  And  your answer was very clear

Answer (score 1):

```js
var left = document.getElementById("left");
left.addEventListener("click", moveLeft, false);

var right = document.getElementById("right");
right.addEventListener("click", moveRight, false);

var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var position = 0;
var interval = 685;
var minPos = ("-" + interval) * images.length;
var maxPos = interval * images.length;


//slide image to the left side <--
function moveRight() {
  if (position > (minPos + interval)) {
    position -= interval;
    carousel.style.left = position + "px";
  }

  if (position === (minPos + interval)) {
    right.style.display = "none";
  }

  left.style.display = "block";
}


//slide image to the right side -->
function moveLeft() {
  if (position < (maxPos - interval) && position < 0) {
    position += interval;
    carousel.style.left = position + "px";
  }

  if (position === 0) {
    left.style.display = "none";
  }

  right.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
 #container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 100px;
   width: 680px;
   height: 360px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 #carousel {
   position: absolute;
   width: 2740px;
   height: 360px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: left 300ms linear;
 }
 .slide {
   display: inline-block;
   height: 360px;
   width: 680px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   transition: left 300ms linear;
 }
 .slideImage {
   position: relative;
   height: 360px;
   width: 680px;
   float: left;
 }
 .button {
   position: absolute;
   top: 340px;
   height: 60px;
   width: 60px;
   border-bottom: 12px solid red;
 }
 #left {
   left: 115px;
   border-left: 12px solid red;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   display: none;
 }
 #right {
   left: 693px;
   border-right: 12px solid red;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slideImage" class="active" src="sithCover.png" alt="slide1">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slideImage" src="darthVader.png" alt="slide2">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slideImage" src="darthSidious.png" alt="slide3">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="slideImage" src="kyloRen.png" alt="slide4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="left" class="button"></div>
<div id="right" class="button"></div>
```

Comment: Hello Jorrex, thank you for your answer.  I see that it worked in the snippet but I found that just by changing it the way NachoDawg explained it was simpler

Comment: sure no prob :) I was just messing around with your code and this is my implementation.